# Equinumerousity of two sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Given two infinite sets $A$ and $B$, I'm asked to show that the two sets $\mathcal{P}(B)^A$ and $\mathcal{P}(A)^B$ are equipotent. I proved it by showing that those two sets have the same cardinality (${(2^{|B|})}^{|A|}$ and ${(2^{|A|})}^{|B|}$ respectively, which are both equal to $2^{|A||B|}$ under the laws of cardinal exponentiation [that's correct, right?]).

All is well, but I'm interested in proving the same claim by constructing a bijective function between those two sets instead, but I'm not sure how.
Can it be proved this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be proved by showing an explicit bijection. Each step in the following sequence of equalities can be shown by a bijection, and it is easy to explain the composition of bijections.

$$\begin{align}
\left|\mathcal{P}(B)^A\right|
 &=\left|\left(2^B\right)^A\right| \\[2 ex]
 &=\left|2^{B\times A}\right| \\[2 ex]
 &=\left|2^{A\times B}\right| \\[2 ex]
 &=\left|\left(2^A\right)^B\right| \\[2 ex]
 &=\left|\mathcal{P}(A)^B\right|
\end{align}$$

Each of those steps has a standard bijection. Ask if you cannot continue from here.

Comment: Ah! Should have attacked the problem by dividing it into steps instead of trying to derive a bijection directly from the start and end sets :)